# Poiseullie equation proof doubt

Tags: homework-and-exercises, viscosity

[image]
In the picture from the proof poiseuille equation for viscosity is there any way to prove it without using the navier stokes equations in the highlighted part.If it is not possible please suggest a good book/source for checking out the navier stokes equations.
This page can be reached by:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Liquid_flow_through_a_pipe

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: I could not explain my doubt without using the picture(to point out the part). I will try my best to write my doubt down without using any pictures

Comment: You can just link to the Wikipedia article and then quote the sentence you high-lighted instead of screen-shotting it, can't you?

Comment: One thing that you can do is to just verify that this solution satisfy the Navier-Stokes equation.